# Filtering devices on Google Play

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I have a published app that supports minimumSDK 9
In order to filter out unsupported screen densities and sizes I add the following code on my manifest file: This insures only hdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi/xxxhdpi devices are supported (SmartPhone and tablets. not including small screen sizes)

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="560"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="640"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="560"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="640"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="560"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="640"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>
```

After publishing to Google Play I notice that a majority of devices with xhdpi density that supposed to be supported are not.
I noticed a new way for filtering screens on Google Play using the  tag but it has a constraint of minimumSDK 13.
After trying this code (which is supposed to do just the same)  I noticed that all the unsupported screens are now available.

```
 <supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="240"-->
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"/>
```

Problem is, I cannot use the second method because I support minimumSDK 9.

Anyone encountered this before and has some insight on why this is happening or what am i doing wrong here?

Many thanks

EDIT

The second code block is not that correct as it will make ldpi devices available as well the value should be 480. Still there is no reason why a lot of tablet devices are unsupported using the  code above.

Comment: you can use the method for devices honeycomb and over (13) , therefore your issue is only with Gingerbread and Froyo devices

Comment: I wish to avoid signing two apk files. putting both blocks of code in the manifest is allowed?

Comment: it is allowed, do it and you will see! `targetSdk=21`

Comment: Incorrect I am afraid. Using both blocks of code in the same manifest file causes the second block to be ignored due to the minimumSDK 9 feature. Don't see a way to avoid 2 apks

Comment: yes it is ignored but on devices below 13. Why don't you just create a few APK's and start to upload them to Google Play so you can see what devices are filtered

Comment: I did. The play console still filters devices that should not be filtered. Galaxy note 2014 for instance and a lot more tablet devices